# rearrange charts in powerpoint using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, charts, powerpoint

I created some graphs in Excel using VBA. Now I would like to send it to my PP template and arrange 4 charts in the same slide, then skip to the next slide and add another 4 charts. All charts need to be resized and rearranged.
I managed to export the first 4 charts, but when I want to arrange them and fit the size then I run in to problems. I have limited VBA experience and no experience using VBA together with MS PP.

My code so far:

```
    Dim PPT As Object
    Dim chr
    Set PPT = CreateObject("Powerpoint.Application")
    PPT.Visible = True
    PPT.Presentations.Open Filename:="C:\VBA Projects\XXX\XXX.ppt"
'    Set PPT = Nothing
    PPT.ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide 4
    For Each chr In Sheets("Output").ChartObjects
        chr.Select
        ActiveChart.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Size:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
        PPT.ActiveWindow.View.Paste
    Next chr

End Sub
```

How can I choose between the charts and manipulate them individually?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After pasting the chart into the slide, you can use the following code to refer to and set the properties for the currently pasted chart.

```
    With PPT.ActiveWindow.View.Slide
        With .Shapes(.Shapes.Count)
            'set properties for shape
            '
            '
        End With
    End With
```

By the way, I would suggest that you replace...

```
ActiveChart.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Size:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
```

with

```
chr.Chart.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Size:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
```

Otherwise, you'll get an error if the worksheet containing the chart is not the active sheet.

**EDIT**

The following code will loop through each ChartObject object in sheet "Output", and then copy each one to the PowerPoint presentation so that each slide contains 4 charts, starting with the 4th slide.  Change the property settings as desired.

```
Const START_LEFT_POS As Long = 25
Const START_TOP_POS As Long = 60
Const GAP As Long = 30 'gap between charts

Dim LeftPos As Long
LeftPos = START_LEFT_POS

Dim TopPos As Long
TopPos = START_TOP_POS

Dim NextSlideIndex As Long
NextSlideIndex = 4

PPT.ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide NextSlideIndex

With Sheets("Output")
    Dim ChrtIndex As Long
    For ChrtIndex = 1 To .ChartObjects.Count
        .ChartObjects(ChrtIndex).Chart.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Size:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
        PPT.ActiveWindow.View.Paste
        With PPT.ActiveWindow.View.slide
            With .Shapes(.Shapes.Count)
                .Left = LeftPos
                .Top = TopPos
                .Width = 200
                .Height = 200
                If ChrtIndex Mod 2 = 1 Then
                    LeftPos = LeftPos + .Width + GAP
                Else
                    LeftPos = START_LEFT_POS
                    TopPos = TopPos + .Height + GAP
                End If
            End With
        End With
        If ChrtIndex Mod 4 = 0 Then
            LeftPos = START_LEFT_POS
            TopPos = START_TOP_POS
            NextSlideIndex = NextSlideIndex + 1
            PPT.ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide NextSlideIndex
        End If
    Next ChrtIndex
End With
```

Comment: This was very useful, thank you! 
Can I use the same method to arrange the charts next to each other? By default they are placed on top of each other

Comment: I mean if I place the with loop inside the for loop it will arrange all charts on top of each other, but some other place in the slide
.Top = 60
.Height = 250
.Left = 25
.Width = 250

Comment: Amazing! Thank you